# A project created with phoenix 1.7-rc fails to compile

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

I installed Phoenix 1.7-rc along with Elixir 1.14.1 and Erlang/OTP 24. I then created a new project using `mix phx.new` command. The compilation fails with the following error:

```
Unchecked dependencies for environment dev:
* phoenix (Hex package)
  the dependency phoenix 1.7.0-rc.0

  > In apps/trial_web/mix.exs:
    {:phoenix, "~> 1.7.0-rc.0", [env: :prod, repo: "hexpm", hex: "phoenix", override: true]}

  does not match the requirement specified

  > In deps/phoenix_live_view/mix.exs:
    {:phoenix, "~> 1.6.15 or ~> 1.7.0", [env: :prod, hex: "phoenix", repo: "hexpm", optional: false]}

  Ensure they match or specify one of the above in your deps and set "override: true"
** (Mix) Can't continue due to errors on dependencies
```

This is how the dependency is defined in mix.exs

```
{:phoenix, "~> 1.7.0-rc.0", override: true},
```

Since the override: is set to true, my understanding is that it should override any other definitions of itself by other dependencies.

What am I missing?

Edit:
As @delameko pointed out, I am working with an umbrella project, and once I remove `phoenix_live_view` dependency from the root `mix.exs`, I can compile. However, it is not ideal, as I lose the ability to run `mix format` on heex files from the root project.

Edit 2: Since `phoenix_live_view` is required to run "mix format" on ~H/.heex files from the umbrella root and it depends on the `phoenix`, after I add `phoenix` on the root `mix.exs`, the project compiles.

Comment: AFAIK, the `override: true` only affects that specific dependency, but the conflict you hit is with `phoenix_live_view`.  Is there a newer version of `phoenix_live_view` that is compatible with `phoenix` version `1.7.0-rc.0`?  You may need to specify that newer version of `phoenix_live_view` in your `mix.exs`

Comment: There seems to be a bug when building the project as an umbrella.  You can get the project to compile by commenting out the phoenix_live_view dependency in the root mix.exs of the umbrella (note, you won't be able to run `mix format` on heex files from the root of the project).

Comment: @Everett thank you for your comment, I am afraid there is no newer version of `phoenix_live_view`.

Comment: @Delameko you are right. Once I commented out `phoenix_live_view` in the root `mix.exs` of the umbrella project. It compiles. I am adding this fact in my question.